# MySQL select query need some optimization

Tags: php, mysql, join, query-optimization

I'm trying to build a query for search page this my first query, and this is very fast the results load within Milli seconds

**$query** is php variable which is search text

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM 
tbl_product 
WHERE 
((tbl_product.pd_name LIKE '%$query%') 
OR (tbl_product.pd_art LIKE '%$query%') 
OR (tbl_product.pd_srkw LIKE '%$query%')) 
AND pd_bestsell <> 1  
ORDER BY RAND()";
```

But when i build a query with search suggestions table it's very slow and take 2-4 seconds for load. our server is very powerful dedicated one so it cannot be a issue with server.

**sgtexts**= keep suggestion texts

**sgproduct** =keep products ids on suggestion table

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM 
tbl_product,tbl_suggetions 
WHERE 
((tbl_product.pd_name LIKE '%$query%') 
OR (tbl_product.pd_art LIKE '%$query%') 
OR (tbl_product.pd_srkw LIKE '%$query%') 
OR (tbl_suggetions.sgtexts LIKE '%$query%' 
AND tbl_product.pd_id=tbl_suggetions.sgproduct))  
AND pd_bestsell <> 1 
GROUP BY pd_id 
ORDER BY RAND()";
```

can anyone help me for optimize second query please

Comment: `EXPLAIN` should give you the answer. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: Is `tbl_suggetions.sgtexts` indexed? And isn't _suggetions_ a typo?

Comment: Add index on your table

Comment: Thanks mate i index table

Comment: How big is the table?

Comment: Have you looked into `FULLTEXT`?

Comment: product table have around 20k and suggestions around 60k, problem was solved already :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason why you order by random? Removing this will make it faster.

Since you are using `LIKE` operator with `%%`, this will perform a **full table scan** and is by nature slower than using `LIKE` 'example%'.

Also, use a join on your table. Try this

```
SELECT 
        * 
FROM    tbl_product         tbl_product
JOIN    tbl_suggetions      tbl_suggetions ON tbl_suggetions.sgproduct=tbl_product.pd_id
WHERE 
(
(tbl_product.pd_name    LIKE '%$query%')        OR 
(tbl_product.pd_art     LIKE '%$query%')        OR 
(tbl_product.pd_srkw    LIKE '%$query%')        OR 
(tbl_suggetions.sgtexts LIKE '%$query%')
)  
    AND pd_bestsell <> 1 
    GROUP BY pd_id 
    ORDER BY RAND();
```

If the data doesnt need to be randomly ordered, remove the `ORDER BY RAND()`

Comment: You're query has exactly the same efficiency, just has different syntax.

Comment: @SunethKalhara , also make sure you only in the SELECT return the columns that you actually need. Now it will return all columns from both tables.

Comment: @KayNelson the query is very fast my query took 15.3766 sec but this took  0.0728 sec, but i got a problem my query return 71 results but new one only return 47 results, any idea why is that, Thanks

Comment: It most likley has to do with using `OR & AND` in the WHERE query.

Comment: @SunethKalhara I think you can also speed iup your query by using `pd_bestsell != 1`, this will get all pd_bestsell where its not 1. what your are using now could give back where pd_bestsell=0 for instance, is that a possibility?

Comment: @dragoste Just wanted to point out that the "`JOIN`" was wrapped in the WHERE statement with OR, so I have to respectfully disagree that the efficiency is the same :)

Comment: Oh, you're right. Just too many braces in OP's query ;-) Anyway I think, that it's an OP's mistake in his query and he meant to write it as I thought it is. That is probably his issue by the way.

Comment: Add `SQL_NO_CACHE` -- I'll bet it is not fast.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for the two variants.  You may find that they are the same -- that is, the `ON` clause may have been moved to `WHERE`.

Comment: `=0` is more easily optimized than `<>1`.  The Optimizer does not know if there might also be values of `333` and `-789` that would match the latter case.

Comment: Thanks for comments, It seems ok, page load within 2 seconds after apply solution on answer